# Tricky array object manipulation of array of objects with javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I take an array that looks like this ...

```
[
 {name: "vif087-08", color: "red", category: "compute", node: "esxi", filter_key: "vif087-08",},
 {name: "Hard disk 1", color: "blue", category: "nfs", node: "hdd_nas", filter_key: "dev-03:Hard disk 1",},
 {name: "Hard disk 2", color: "blue", category: "nfs", node: "hdd_nas", filter_key: "dev-03:Hard disk 2",},
 {name: "Hard disk 3", color: "blue", category: "nfs", node: "hdd_nas", filter_key: "dev-03:Hard disk 3",},
 {name: "Hard disk 4", color: "blue", category: "nfs", node: "hdd_nas", filter_key: "dev-03:Hard disk 4",},
 {name: "Hard disk 5", color: "blue", category: "nfs", node: "hdd_nas", filter_key: "dev-03:Hard disk 5",},
 {name: "Hard disk 6", color: "blue", category: "nfs", node: "hdd_nas", filter_key: "dev-03:Hard disk 6",},
]
```

... and create a new array that looks like this ...

```
[
  {
    name: "esxi",
    color: "red",
    components: [
      {name: "vif087-08", category: "compute", node: "esxi", filter_key: "vif087-08",}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "hdd_nas",
    color: "blue",
    components: [
      {name: "Hard disk 1", category: "nfs", node: "hdd_nas", filter_key: "dev-03:Hard disk 1",},
      {name: "Hard disk 2", category: "nfs", node: "hdd_nas", filter_key: "dev-03:Hard disk 2",},
      {name: "Hard disk 3", category: "nfs", node: "hdd_nas", filter_key: "dev-03:Hard disk 3",},
      {name: "Hard disk 4", category: "nfs", node: "hdd_nas", filter_key: "dev-03:Hard disk 4",},
      {name: "Hard disk 5", category: "nfs", node: "hdd_nas", filter_key: "dev-03:Hard disk 5",},
      {name: "Hard disk 6", category: "nfs", node: "hdd_nas", filter_key: "dev-03:Hard disk 6",},
    ]
  },
]
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
  buildNewChildren(children:any) {
    // this routine will build left and right children of the center node.
    // the children will be rect for each "node" (e.g. esxi, vm, nas etc.)
    // inside the rect there will be a scrolling list of all the names of the
    // components that are of that type of node.
    let nodes_in_children = children.map(node => node.node);
    let new_children = [];
    for( let i = 0; i < nodes_in_children.length; i++) {
      let new_child = {
        "name": i,
        "color": children[i].color,
        "components": [],
      };
      for( let j = 0; j < children.length; j++){
        if( children[j].node === i) {
          let new_component = {
            "name" : children[j].name,
            "category": children[j].category,
            "node": children[j].node,
            "filter_key": children[j].filter_key,
            "parent": children[j].parent
          };
          new_child.components.push(new_component);
        }
      }
      new_children.push(new_child);''
    }
    return new_children;
  }
```

Needless to say it doesn't work very well.

Comment: What did you try? Please, add your code to the question. then we can help you.

Comment: Fairly standard groupBy operation. Do a search for "array groupBy"

Comment: My attempt was monstrous and too ugly to post :(

Comment: Start with creating an object that uses `node` value as keys. That is the only unique property value you are showing in example. Push each item into associated components array. Then use Object.values to get results

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small script, which does your transform:

```js
const input = [
 {name: "vif087-08", color: "red", category: "compute", node: "esxi", filter_key: "vif087-08",},
 {name: "Hard disk 1", color: "blue", category: "nfs", node: "hdd_nas", filter_key: "dev-03:Hard disk 1",},
 {name: "Hard disk 2", color: "blue", category: "nfs", node: "hdd_nas", filter_key: "dev-03:Hard disk 2",},
 {name: "Hard disk 3", color: "blue", category: "nfs", node: "hdd_nas", filter_key: "dev-03:Hard disk 3",},
 {name: "Hard disk 4", color: "blue", category: "nfs", node: "hdd_nas", filter_key: "dev-03:Hard disk 4",},
 {name: "Hard disk 5", color: "blue", category: "nfs", node: "hdd_nas", filter_key: "dev-03:Hard disk 5",},
 {name: "Hard disk 6", color: "blue", category: "nfs", node: "hdd_nas", filter_key: "dev-03:Hard disk 6",},
]

const resultObj = {};

for(const element of input) {
  if(!(element.node in resultObj)){
    resultObj[element.node] = {};
  }
  if(!(element.color in resultObj[element.node])) {
    resultObj[element.node][element.color] = [];
  }
  resultObj[element.node][element.color].push(element);
}

const output = [];

for(const name in resultObj) {
  for(const color in resultObj[name]){
    output.push({
      name,
      color,
      components: resultObj[name][color]
    });
  }
}

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce to an object that uses node and color values combined as keys and then use `Object.values()` to get resultant array

```js
const groupedObj =  data.reduce((a, {node, color, ...rest}) => {
       const key = `${node}|${color}`;
       a[key] = a[key] || {name:node, color, components:[]};
       a[key].components.push({node, ...rest});
       return a;
   },{});

const res = Object.values(groupedObj);

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important}
```

```html
<script>
  const data = [
 {name: "vif087-08", color: "red", category: "compute", node: "esxi", filter_key: "vif087-08",},
 {name: "Hard disk 1", color: "blue", category: "nfs", node: "hdd_nas", filter_key: "dev-03:Hard disk 1",},
 {name: "Hard disk 2", color: "blue", category: "nfs", node: "hdd_nas", filter_key: "dev-03:Hard disk 2",},
 {name: "Hard disk 3", color: "blue", category: "nfs", node: "hdd_nas", filter_key: "dev-03:Hard disk 3",},
 {name: "Hard disk 4", color: "blue", category: "nfs", node: "hdd_nas", filter_key: "dev-03:Hard disk 4",},
 {name: "Hard disk 5", color: "blue", category: "nfs", node: "hdd_nas", filter_key: "dev-03:Hard disk 5",},
 {name: "Hard disk 6", color: "blue", category: "nfs", node: "hdd_nas", filter_key: "dev-03:Hard disk 6",},
]
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks ... `color` needs to "follow" or "go with" `node`.

Comment: Ok but that needs filtering also? Your example didn't match data...no blue in example results

Comment: Updated to filter node/color combinations